# Left of '.Position' must have class/struct/union

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, linked-list, typedef

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned short int Position; // << That's what i'm trying to change!
    unsigned short int OldPosition;
} Turn_s;

struct Turn_sMap{
    Turn_s *Turn;
    Turn_sMap *NextTurn;
};

New = new Turn_sMap;
New->Turn = new Turn_s;

New->Turn.Position = 0; // Already tried (New->Turn).Position = 0;
```

Why I get that compile error? Am i not accessing the struct Turn inside the struct New, which in turn has a member called Position? Or does typedef messes the struct type with some pointer craziness?? Help please, I'm lost! ):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration `Turn_s *Turn;` makes `Turn` a pointer type. To access member objects you need to use `->` operator. Try:

```
New->Turn->Position = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Turn_sMap::Turn` is a pointer. You need to dereference it:

```
New->Turn->Position = 0;
```

In addition, you shouldn't be using `typedef struct` in C++. Just declare the structs:

```
struct Turn_s {
    unsigned short int Position; // << That's what i'm trying to change!
    unsigned short int OldPosition;
};

Turn_s a;
foo(a);
```

Comment: I though i had to use it to avoid putting "struct"'s everywhere... Thanks!

Comment: That's happens in C, not C++ :D